# Position fixed within parent that has -webkit-perspective

Tags: css, 3d, transform, fixed, perspective

I am implementing a 3D interface using jQuery Isotope and Infinite Scrolling. The Loading message for the infinite scrolling should be `position: fixed`. However, because its parent has a `-webkit-perspective` set, then it seems to revert to `absolute` positioning.

Is this a known bug, or is this just typically how 3D transforms affect their children?

Answer (score 4):

Any time you apply a transform to an element it becomes a positioning root for positioned children. Your `position:fixed` element will become fixed relative to the transformed parent.

This is implemented in current Webkit and Gecko (at least, they’re the two I’ve got handy to test it), and is detailed in section 6 of the Transforms specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-property